# Salesforce lightning - switch on in January

Tags: lightning-experience, salesforce-classic

I asked my colleagues on the admin team if we need to prepare for salesforce switching on lightning starting Jan 2020. I thought we might need to switch on in a Sandbox and learn the new navigation, adjust page layouts etc. However their reply was the following:  'all custom objects and processes break when converted to lightening experience'

I was not aware that turning on Lightning would break so many things - can someone help me confirm if custom objects all break when switching over from classic?

Comment: That is completely false. Processes, triggers, rules and that kind of components are not impacted at all. Only Visualforce pages and buttons could break.

Comment: You can check the following trailhead and take advantage of  Lightning Experience readiness and Rollout strategy. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_migration_rollout/lex_migration_rollout_educating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a misunderstanding about the "automated switch" to Lightning that will occur in Jan 2020. This switch only applies to **users** with **Standard Profiles**.

If your org only uses **Custom Profiles**, you will **not** be affected by it. Only users who have Standard Profiles will be *automatically switched* to Lightning by Salesforce. Detail Record Pages that aren't compatible with Lightning will still open in Classic for users with a Custom Profile but expect them to "break" for users with a Standard Profile.

You'll want to do your homework to know what will happen your org. The simplest solution to this issue is to clone any Standard Profiles you're using and replace them with Custom Profiles.